# Start a review submission for an app without facebook login

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a web app from which users can schedule messages to be posted to their social networks. My app doesn't use Facebook as a login mechanism to access it, you login using a regular user. Facebook Login is done inside the app when users explicitly ask to, so they can select where (wall, list, group, etc.) their messages would get posted.

Is Login with Facebook required for my app review to be successful?
Thanks

Comment: We only review permissions. Without Facebook Login you can't ask for any permissions and there is no reason to get reviewed

Comment: Sorry I probably didn't write it down well. What I meant is that my app doesn't use Facebook as a logon mechanism to access it. I do use Facebook login but once you have logged in with a regular user. Would I get my submission rejected by that?  I'll edit the post to make that more clear. Thanks

Comment: No you will not get rejected because of it.